# What's wrong with my Robolectric LocationManager test? Why my listener isn't registered?

Tags: android, observer-pattern, robolectric

I am pretty much a newbie with Android *and* Robolectric; I'm kind of stuck with a unit test for a LocationListener in which I am attempting to feed it certain location values and see what happens.

I have this:

```
@Test
    public void foo() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                RuntimeEnvironment.application.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ShadowLocationManager shadowLocationManager = shadowOf(locationManager);
        // MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
        MyLocationListener instance = MyLocationListener.getInstance(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
        Location expectedLocation = getLocation(NETWORK_PROVIDER, 12.0, 34.0);
        shadowLocationManager.simulateLocation(expectedLocation);
    }
```

Now, `MyLocationListener` is never updated.

Moreover, if I debug the test and follow the execution of `simulateLocation` from Robolectric's ShadowLocationmanager, I have `providerListeners == null`, so it actually does nothing:

```
public class ShadowLocationManager {
    // ... 
    public void simulateLocation(Location location) {
        this.cleanupRemovedLocationListeners();
        this.setLastKnownLocation(location.getProvider(), location);
        List providerListeners = (List)this.locationListeners.get(location.getProvider());
        if(providerListeners != null) {
             // It never enters here
        }
    }
```

Why? Any clue?

Comment: Could you add the code for MyLocationListener as well? The problem could be there. Is requestLocationUpdates() ever called as part of the test?